# pipenv shell vs pipenv run (with scripts)

Tags: python, homebrew, pipenv

While following [this tutorial by tds](https://towardsdatascience.com/parsing-fitness-tracker-data-with-python-a59e7dc17418),I decided to do it through pipenv since I'm on macos. I managed to get most done, but I kept running into an error that suggests I don't understand how pipenv sets up an environment. Specifically, with how it runs scripts. It seems to revert to relying on my system python (2.7) even from within the pipenv shell. (the parse_gpx.py is the main python file while the 2021-0622run.gpx is the gpx format file that will be analyzed)

- "pipenv shell" and then run the command "pipenv run python parse_gpx.py 2021-0622run.gpx" results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_gpx.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.so not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

- "pipenv run python parse_gpx.py 2021-0622run.gpx" produces the expected table.

**my question is: why does it appear that "pipenv shell" looks in the system python rather than staying in its own "box?"** wasn't that the whole point of pipenv? is it possible I configured something wrong? I did have a few problems setting it up (including double installs and other things) which is why I'm not sure if this behavior is by design, or a remnant of my previous botched installs.

Any help pointing me to documentation that explains what is going on would be appreciated!

And finally, sorry if this is in the wrong place. I tried looking for the best place to ask this and also checked if anyone had asked this before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you also installed [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)? Without PyEnv, PipEnv cannot install the required Python version for you.

Secondly, when you created your environment, did you remember to specify the Python version? To create an environment with the latest Python 3 release, use `pipenv --three`.

Comment: A bit misleading. pipenv does not depend or require pyenv. It will use pyenv "*[if pyenv is available](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/#pipenv-features)*" You can use install Python by any means, and then tell pipenv to use the correct version with `--python`. I have 4 versions of Python and working well with pipenv, completely *without pyenv*

Comment: Thank you for your responses! As to your questions:
1. I installed Pyenv first.
2. I specified the Python version as 3.7 in the environment of interest as it was the most compatible (other versions caused problems).
To offer more insight (the following is from within the shell):
1. "pipenv run python file.py" = "python file.py" at least with most files I get the same output
2. python --version returns 3.7.10, the version I configured the local file to use.
3. I created a little script to return the version I was running and in both above cases, it reports 3.7.10. Error above unchanged.